# What is the translation for "You are Matched"?

Tags: tradução, palavra-para-ideia

So I need to input this in a string for a software.

When two people match each other (like each other) the software will say:

> You are matched!

How can I put this in a Portuguese version that is short and simple?

Edit: This match which I forgot to mention has nothing to do with a relationship type of match. It simply means that two random people followed each other. The original term is "You are Matched" which I unfortunately can't change.

Comment: «Vocês são compatíveis!»?

Comment: Vocês combinam.

Comment: There is a problem here. Software match é uma correspôndencia feita pelo programa. To match two people. Então quer dizer que essas duas pessaos foram postas juntas. Foram juntadas pelo programa. No fundo. é casar mesmo. :) No sentido: Essa calça casa com essa blusa?

Comment: LOL! The thing I forgot to mention is that the pars can be of either sex and it occurs for the simple fact of someone liking each other. As in, similar to a Facebook like..  No sentimental meaning at all. I should've added this to the question but I totally forgot to observe how it could've been observed from different perspectives.

Comment: Hugo, I've edited my answer, wrote a new one really, in light of your edit.

Comment: @Hugo : Could you give us some replacements in English? It would be possible to be changed by: "Someone has found you"; "We found someone to you"; "Someone has a crush on you";...

Answer (score 4):

Em se tratando de um site de relacionamentos, e dependendo do meu público, eu diria:

- Encontramos tua cara-metade.
- Encontramos teu par perfeito.
- Encontramos tua alma-gêmea.

> - [**cara-metade**](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=cara-metade+defini%C3%A7%C3%A3o&rlz=1C1ARAB_enBR495BR495&oq=cara-metade+defini%C3%A7%C3%A3o&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.5759j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) - "o parceiro amoroso com quem se pode encontrar mais afinidades"
> - [**alma gêmea**](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=cara-metade+defini%C3%A7%C3%A3o&rlz=1C1ARAB_enBR495BR495&oq=cara-metade+defini%C3%A7%C3%A3o&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.5759j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=alma+g%C3%AAmea+defini%C3%A7%C3%A3o+dicion%C3%A1rio) - "pessoa com quem se tem profundas afinidades, geralmente em relacionamento amoroso."
> - [**par**](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/busca?r=0&f=0&t=0&palavra=par) -  "conjunto de duas pessoas, objetos, animais etc. iguais ou que apresentam a mesma natureza"

Embora os dicionários portugueses citem "cara-metade" apenas como sinônimo de esposa, em pt-BR o termo se aplica a qualquer um dos parceiros.

Answer (score 1):

## New answer

It seems you are trying to find an expression for two persons who followed each other (let's consider for example in twitter). I would say that this can happen for many reasons and people don't really to have a relationship in real life (i.e they don't have to like each other, or even know each other).

If the relevant message is that **two persons are now following each other** I would go for:

> Você e o João estão seguindo-se. (You and João are following each other)

[Seguir is quite common around social networks](https://www.google.co.uk/search?espv=2&q=%22siga-nos%20no%20facebook%22&oq=%22siga-nos%20no%20facebook%22&gs_l=serp.3..0i7i30k1j0i30k1j0i7i30k1.9313.13880.0.14160.3.3.0.0.0.0.56.145.3.3.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..0.3.143...0j0i22i30k1.iWmWbW_KyNQ)

If the relevant message is that **there is a mutual retribution (they like each other twitter posts, for example) that resulted in them following each other** see @Jacinto answer. I prefered his `Você é correspondido` suggestion.

This expression can have the advantage of including the meaning that two persons are alike according to the 2nd definition of [Priberam](https://www.priberam.pt/DLPO/corresponder)

> Ser igual, equivaler, retribuir condignamente.

## Old answer

If the intent is to match two people according to their interests, like the question suggested I would go for parceiro(a):

> Encontrámos um(a) parceiro(a) (We found a match/partner)

In priberam you can find the defenition of [parceiro](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/parceiro)

> (latim partiarius, -a, -um, que tem uma parte) adjectivo
>
> 1. Que tem poucas diferenças em relação a outro. = PAR, PARELHO, SEMELHANTE substantivo masculino
> 2. Pessoa ou entidade que está em parceria com outra para atingir o mesmo objectivo. = COMPANHEIRO, COMPARTE, PAR, QUINHOEIRO, SÓCIO
> 3. A pessoa com quem se joga ou dança.
> 4. [Regionalismo]  Tratamento recíproco dos que foram mordomos numa festividade ou confraria no mesmo ano.
> 5. [Regionalismo]  Tratamento recíproco dos pais dos cônjuges.
> 6. [Popular]  Pessoa que tem esperteza. = ESPERTALHÃO, FINÓRIO

The word parceiro can be used to refer to someone that is alike (1st definition "whom that has little difference with someonelse")

Or to refer to someone that I like (2nd definition "human, or entity, that is on a partnership to reach the same goal)

It would even fit on a game, if you were developing one (3rd definition  "A person to play with")

Comment: Eh pá, soice, se é porque eles gostam um do outro, acho que e é mais a 2 e 3 que são relevantes aqui

Comment: @Jacinto Fiquei na dúvida no que o AP quiz dizer com "like each other" (se sao parecidos, ou se gostam um dum outro). Mas posso amendar um bocado a resposta.

Comment: Não é impossível a tua interpretação, mas eu nesse caso teria escrito *(are like each other)*

Comment: @BrunoCosta Na verdade, significa os dois: ambas as partes expressaram o desejo de conhecer a outra, e ambas as partes são suficientemente similares para serem emparelhadas pelo software. Mas sua sugestão já inclui os dois significados (pelo menos na atual edição).

Comment: Bruno, I disavow your interpretation of my suggestion *és correspndido*. I specifically and primarilly mean that two people like each other's stuff, not primarilly that they have something in common (although they must have in some degree) and not al all that they are alike.For instance, you follow with interest my etymology answers, and **és correspondido** because I follow with no less interest your grammar answers.

Comment: @Jacinto I see. I think I edited the offending bit of my answer while still saying that `corresponder` can also mean `to be alike`

Comment: Thanks, that's better. But not quite there yet. I just mean João follows me (presumably because he likes stuff I do) and I follow him; not because he follows me, but because I'm interested in his stuff. Yes, *corresponder* has several meanings; but "to be alike" is not relevant in my answer.

Comment: ("posso amendar"... deves ser informático, Bruno, não? ;)

Comment: @ANeves Sou pois, mas nao é isso que me impediu de escrever um livro de poesia.